# How to make divider ignore padding of parent in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am trying to create a layout in which the parent of the content has horizontal padding, but the divider between content items should ignore the padding on the right side.

To make it more clear, I made this drawing of what I want:
[image: drawing of layout that uses divider that ignores padding of parent]

Now, I got something to work by using the `Modifier.offset(x=16.dp)` and that did the trick *except* that now the divider is now too 'short' on the left side, like this:
[image: drawing of layout that ignores the padding but left side is too short]How can I achieve such a layout? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `offset` modifier doesn't work because you are just applying an offset without changing the width.
You can use the **`layout`** modifier to specify the size and the position where the element should be placed.

Something like:

```
   Divider(
       color = Black,
       modifier = Modifier
        .layout(){ measurable, constraints ->
            val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints.copy(
                maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth + 16.dp.roundToPx(), //add the end padding 16.dp
            ))
            layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                placeable.place(8.dp.roundToPx(), 0) 
            }
      }
   )
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

We have a few components in our grid that needs to go full width. Based on Gabriele's answer, I made this a reusable custom modifier:

```
fun Modifier.fillWidthOfParent(parentPadding: Dp) = this.then(
  layout { measurable, constraints ->
    // This is to force layout to go beyond the borders of its parent
    val placeable = measurable.measure(
        constraints.copy(
            maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth + 2 * parentPadding.roundToPx(),
        ),
    )
    layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
        placeable.place(0, 0)
    }
  },
)
```

When I want a component to bypass parent's padding and go full screen, I pass this modifier instead of fillMaxWidth(). The argument passed is the padding of the parent. You can assign it a default value if your app screen has consistent page margins (which is hopefully the case)